# SQL Dependency is not working After Publish in Cloud Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2016, sqldependency

I am creating a SqlDependency notification by using WebApi 2.0. In the local machine, everything is working properly. After deploying the API in Cloud server notification is not firing; means the OnChange event is not firing.

How to solve this issue? I am using WebApi 2.0, SQL SERVER 2016, IIS 7